# Convert a list of selected days to its hyponym

Tags: ios, ios5

I have list of days (from monday till sunday).
When a user selects monday till friday or saturday and sunday I want my app to show it's hyponym (weekdays/weekends).

Does iOS provide some default functionality for this (If i'm not mistaken the iOS Alarm app does the same) or do I have to write this functionality myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you have a `NSArray` with the selected days as numbers, named `selectedDays`, and that 0 and 6 are weekend days:

```
NSString *name = nil; // Fill this with the default values (concatenate all names of selected days)
bool days[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
for (NSNumber *day in selectedDays)
{
    int d = [day intValue];
    if (d >= 0 && d <= 6) days[d] = true;
}

if (   days[0] == true
    && days[1] == false
    && days[2] == false
    && days[3] == false
    && days[4] == false
    && days[5] == false
    && days[6] == true)
{
    name = @"Weekend";
}

if (   days[0] == false
    && days[1] == true
    && days[2] == true
    && days[3] == true
    && days[4] == true
    && days[5] == true
    && days[6] == false)
{
    name = @"Weekdays";
}
```